# Shifting 2D-matrices in both directions (diagonally) at the same time?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to shift a 2D square matrix in both x and y directions at the same time (diagonally). Is there any way in Python to do this? Please see the attached figure.

[image]

Comment: is roll what you are looking for? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html Also, it's a good idea to show what you have tried so far. Generally, people are more open to answering your question if they see you did your due diligence: googled beyond the first page, tried different things yourself, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.roll()` for each axis:

```py
>>> x = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4, 4)
>>> x
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> np.roll(x, 2, axis=(0,1))
array([[11, 12,  9, 10],
       [15, 16, 13, 14],
       [ 3,  4,  1,  2],
       [ 7,  8,  5,  6]])
```

Comment: Or you can use `np.roll()` once, with axis specifying both 0 and 1: `np.roll(x, 2, axis=(0, 1))` :)

Comment: My bad @RafazZ I didn't even see that you commented while I was typing my answer.

Comment: @Skylimit if this answer solved your problem, can you mark it as accepted so that your question is removed from the unanswered queue?